# Problems with query speed when using a nested query for item count

Tags: mysql

When I add the nested query for **invCount**, my query time goes from .03 sec to 14 sec.  The query works and I get correct values, but it is very, very slow in comparison.  Is that just because I have to many conditions in that query?  When I take it out and still have the second nested query, the time is still .03 secs.  There is clearly something about the first nested query the database doesn't like, but I am not seeing what it is.  I have a foreign key set for all the inner join lines too.  Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

```
SELECT  a.*,  
    f.name, 
    f.partNumber, 
    f.showInAdminStore, 
    f.showInPublicStore, 
    f.productImage, 
    r.mastCatID,
    (SELECT COUNT(b.inventoryID) 
        FROM storeInventory b 
        INNER JOIN events c ON c.eventID = b.eventID
        WHERE b.pluID = a.pluID 
        AND b.listPrice = a.listPrice
        AND b.unlimitedQty = a.unlimitedQty
        AND (b.packageID = a.packageID OR (b.packageID IS NULL AND a.packageID IS NULL))
        AND b.orderID IS NULL
        AND c.isOpen = '1'
        AND b.paymentTypeID <= '2'
        AND (b.inCart < '$cartTime' OR b.inCart IS NULL) ) AS invCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(x.inventoryID) 
        FROM storeInventory x 
        WHERE x.packageID = a.inventoryID) AS packageCount  
    FROM storeInventory a 
    INNER JOIN storePLUs f ON f.pluID = a.pluID
    INNER JOIN storeCategories r ON r.catID = f.catID
    INNER JOIN events d ON d.eventID = a.eventID
    WHERE a.storeFrontID = '1' 
    AND a.orderID IS NULL
        AND a.paymentTypeID <= '2'
    AND d.isOpen = '1'
    GROUP BY a.packageID, a.unlimitedQty, a.listPrice, a.pluID
```

[Table from query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeMLm.png)

UPDATE: 12/12/2022

I changed the line checking the packageID to "AND (b.packageID <=> a.packageID)" as suggested and that cut my query time down to 7.8 seconds from 14 seconds. Thanks for the pointer. I will definitely use that in the future for NULL comparisons.

using "count(*)" took about half a second off. When I take the first nested query out, it drops down to .05 seconds even with the other nested queries in there, so I feel like there is still something causing issues. I tried running it without the other "AND (b.inCart < '$cartTime' OR b.inCart IS NULL)" line and that did take about a second off, but no where what I was hoping for. Is there an operand that includes NULL on a less than comparison? I also tried running it without the inner join in the nested query and that didn't change much at all.  Of course removing any of that, throughs the values off and they become incorrect, so I can't run it that way.

Here is my current query setup that still pulls correct values.

```
SELECT  a.*,  
    f.name, 
    f.partNumber, 
    f.showInAdminStore, 
    f.showInPublicStore, 
    f.productImage, 
    r.mastCatID,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM storeInventory b 
        INNER JOIN events c ON c.eventID = b.eventID
        WHERE b.pluID = a.pluID 
        AND b.listPrice = a.listPrice
        AND b.unlimitedQty = a.unlimitedQty
        AND (b.packageID <=> a.packageID)
        AND b.orderID IS NULL
        AND c.isOpen = '1'
        AND b.paymentTypeID <= '2'
        AND (b.inCart < '$cartTime' OR b.inCart IS NULL) ) AS invCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(x.inventoryID) 
        FROM storeInventory x 
        WHERE x.packageID = a.inventoryID) AS packageCount  
    FROM storeInventory a 
    INNER JOIN storePLUs f ON f.pluID = a.pluID
    INNER JOIN storeCategories r ON r.catID = f.catID
    INNER JOIN events d ON d.eventID = a.eventID
    WHERE a.storeFrontID = '1' 
    AND a.orderID IS NULL
        AND a.paymentTypeID <= '2'
    AND d.isOpen = '1'
    GROUP BY a.packageID, a.unlimitedQty, a.listPrice, a.pluID
```

I am not familiar with the term 'Composite indexes'  Is that something different than these?
[Screenshot of ForeignKeys on Table a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTWqn.png)

Comment: Nested queries have horrible performance, as you are discovering. For every row, the db engine has to run the nested query, which kills performance. Instead, use an inline subquery. By moving it to the FROM clause, the subquery executes once, instead of once per row.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: @SamM, I think I am following what you are saying, but my inventory table currently has an individual row for every item, even if they are duplicates.  So on the webpage, I am using the query to group them by matching inventory items and I was trying to use the nested query to find a total for each matching item.  Are you saying that can be done in the FROM clause and still get an individual total for unique item? I will post a screen shot of the table it is generating so you can see that.

Answer (score 0):

I *think*

```
              AND  (b.packageID = a.packageID
                      OR  (b.packageID IS NULL
                              AND  a.packageID IS NULL)
                   )
```

can be simplified to ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to ):

```
    AND ( b.packageID <=> a.packageID )
```

Use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(x.inventoryID)` unless you check for not-NULL.

The subquery to compute `packageCount` seems strange; you seem to count inventories but join on packages.

The need to reach into another table to check `isOpen` is part of the performance problem.  If `eventID is not the` PRIMARY KEY`for`events`, then add` INDEX(eventID, isOpen)`.

Some other indexes that may help:

```
a:  INDEX(storeFrontID, orderID, paymentTypeID)
a:  INDEX(packageID, unlimitedQty, listPrice, pluID)
b:  INDEX(pluID, listPrice, unlimitedQty, orderID)
f:  INDEX(pluID, catID)
r:  INDEX(catID, mastCatID)
x:  INDEX(packageID,  inventoryID)
```

**After OP's Update**

There is no way to do `(x<y OR x IS NULL)` except by switching to a `UNION`.  In your case, it is pretty easy to do the conversion.  Replace

```
( SELECT COUNT(*) ... AND (    b.inCart < '$cartTime'
                            OR b.inCart IS NULL     ) ) AS invCount,
```

with

```
( SELECT COUNT(*) ... AND b.inCart < '$cartTime' ) + 
( SELECT COUNT(*) ... AND b.inCart IS NULL       ) AS invCount,
```

Revised indexes:

```
storePLUs:
  INDEX(pluID, catID)
storeCategories:
  INDEX(catID,  mastCatID)
events:
  INDEX(isOpen, eventID)
storeInventory:
  INDEX(pluID, listPrice, unlimitedQty, orderID, packageID)
  INDEX(pluID, listPrice, unlimitedQty, orderID, inCart)
  INDEX(packageID,  inventoryID)
  INDEX(storeFrontID, orderID, paymentTypeID)
```

Comment: @BoHarris - Please edit your Question to add the current formulation of the query and its timing.  Did you add the composite indexes, too?

Comment: Updated the original post above